# Should hashmap key be immutable?

Tags: object, hashmap

I have a question, if we need to pass custom object as a key, we just need to override equals and hashcode methods or even the class should be immutable?

because string is immutable so we prefer it as a key in hashmap, so with that logic i have raised this question ?

Comment: It would be better

Comment: Thanks ! @MauricePerry

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hashing function.

All data that is being hashed *should* be immutable. Otherwise you will lose access to your value once you alter one of those fields, until you pass another object which hashes the same way. The odds of finding your value again using any other key object is quite low.